# C# Get content type of a response without loading entire content

Tags: c#, types, request, response

I want to make sure from those who know if the following lines of code will only get the response type of the request without loading the full content, because i have to to some conditions over response type in my application and i dont want to waste time for that resources that should be ignored.

```
request = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var responseType = response.ContentType;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easiest to set the [`Method` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.method.aspx) to `"HEAD"` - that way you won't get the actual contents, just the headers.

On the other hand, that does mean you'll need to make two requests when you *do* want the contents...

Answer (score -1):

Please use below code to get the data in response string

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "application/json";

try
    {
        WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
        using (Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            if (webStream != null)
            {
                using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream))
                {
                    string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                    JObject objjson = JObject.Parse(response);

                    var obj= (from p in objjson["YourobjectList"].Children()
                                      select p).ToList();

                   

                }
            }
        }
    }
catch (Exception ex) {
}
```